# How to authorize all urls of a particular domain for callback with dotnetopenauth

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

I'm using dotnetopenauth right now to create a authentication server using the OAuth2 protocol and it works fine so far. But there's something I can't figure out : the clients of my authentication service will provide a callback url that will change depending on many use cases. What I would want to do is to only give the domain  to dotnetopenauth so every callback url from that host will be authorized.

To me, it doesn't look like a unusual scenario so I wonder why I can't find any docs on this.

Thanks

Comment: From what I remember doing exactly the same thing, an empty callback url means that any url is accepted.

Comment: I want to accept only urls from a specific domain, not all urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I found a way fix this. I don't know if it's the best way but it works. The trick was to subclass the **ClientDescription** class and to override the IsCallbackAllowed method to put in the validation logic you need.

If you have other suggestions, please share.

Thanks.